# Display Joomla module with php

Tags: php, database, joomla

extremelly need help with php request to database. I wrote a code which should display module in new php file

```html
<?php
$db = new mysqli('server', login', 'pass', 'db');
$query = 'SELECT * FROM k7c1b_modules WHERE id = "339"';
$result = $db->query($query);  
$row = $result->fetch_row();
echo $row;
$result->close();
?>
```

But as a result I see only message "Array". If I write echo $row[1]; I see module's Id. But how to make my code display whole module?

Answer (score 0):

The row is an array. Access vars by column name like this:

```
echo $row['columnNameHere'];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the module itself to display, I recommend just loading a module position instead.  Then you can assign whatever module(s) to that page. Will make it a lot easier if you want to change the module or unpublish it.
Make sure load plugin "Content - Load Modules" is enabled and in the PHP just put in:

```html
<?php echo JHtml::_('content.prepare', '{loadposition mijo-header}'); ?>
```

Make sure your PHP is loading all the Joomla stuff in the beginning if not in an actual component or whatnot.